# Is a representation of a $k$-algebra a $k$-vector space?

Tags: representation-theory

> Is a representation $V$ of an $k$-algebra $A$ a $k$-vector space ?

I've been studying representation theory for some weeks, but sometimes I get a little bit confused about all the different operators that are defined. So I'm trying to structurize it a little bit:

So an $k$-algebra $A$ is a set with

1. $+$ addition
2. $\overset{1}{.}$ scalar multiplication with scalars in $k$
3. $\cdot $ multiplication

Then we got a representation $V$ which is a set with:

1. $+$ addition
2. $\overset{2}{.}$ scalar multiplication (with scalars in $k$?)
3. $\overset{3}{\cdot }$ some other kind of scalar multiplication but then with scalars in $A$

So I seem to have three different scalar multiplication, are they somehow related ? Is a representation $V$ of a $k$-algebra $A$ a $k$-vector space ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A representation of a $k$-algebra $A$ is a $k$-vector space $E$ together with an action of $A$ on $E$ by endomorphisms, i.e., a homomorphism from $A$ to $End_k(E)$. 
More generally, a representation of an algebra is a module for that algebra.

Comment: How do you know ?

Comment: How do I know ? From the definition ! See for example [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M250.04/kalgebra.html), it's from Elkies [Higher Algebra](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M250.04/).

Comment: That is not the definition that I am given. http://math.mit.edu/~etingof/replect.pdf see page 7. In the beginning they say that an algebra is always a vector space over some algebraically closed field $k$. But they don't say that about $V$.

Comment: In definition 1.9 they don't say that $V$ is a $k$-vector space. They only say that it is a vector space. They don't say that the scalars of the vector spaces $V$ and $A$ are the same.

Comment: @Kasper Once you have the action of a $k$-algebra, you also get an action of $k$, and hence a $k$-vector space.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Okay, I get that. Thanks. So therefore $(V,\rho)$ is a $k$ vector space, where $\rho$ is this action. But $V$ in its own right, is that also a $k$ vector space. Or could it have other scalars ?

Comment: @Kasper Well, of course it could have actions of other fields, but that is not really relevant.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft